# Behat pressButton not working in laravel 5

Tags: php, testing, behat, laravel-5

https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-5-and-behat-driving-authentication

This is the tutorial by Jeoffery Way that I am testing

This is the scenario that I am trying to test

```
Scenario: Adding a new school
When I add a new school with "Narendra School" "This is a cool school"
Then I should see "Add School"
And a school is created
```

This is my feature context file,

```
/**
* @When I add a new school with :arg1 :arg2
*/
public function iAddANewSchoolWith($name , $description )
{
    $this->visit('school/create');
    $this->fillField( 'name', $name );
    $this->fillField( 'description', $description );
    $this->pressButton('register');
}

/**
* @Then a school is created
*/
public function aSchoolIsCreated()
{
   $school = School::all();
   PHPUnit::assertEquals($school->isEmpty(), false );
}
```

This is my html code

```
<form method="post">
<h2>Add School</h2>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! Session::getToken() !!}"/>

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    <button name="register">Register</button>
</form>
```

This is the controller method that i am using to create the object

```
function create( ) {

   if ( \Request::isMethod( 'post' ) ) {

     $this->school->add( \Input::all() );// I am using a repository and dependency injection so this code is fine, it will add a school
   }

   return view('school::school.add');
}
```

When I hit the url, fill the form and hit register in the browser, I save a new school but when I run the test, I cannot seem to create the school.
The test is running I can see the html when I do a `printLastResponse()`

```
Feature: Testing
    In order to teach Behat
    As a teacher
    I want to add a new school

  Scenario: Adding a new school                                            # features\example.feature:6
    When I add a new school with "Narendra School" "This is a cool school" # FeatureContext::iAddANewSchoolWith()
    Then I should see "Add School"                                         # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And a school is created                                                # FeatureContext::aSchoolIsCreated()
      Failed asserting that false matches expected true.

--- Failed scenarios:

    features\example.feature:6

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (2 passed, 1 failed)
0m3.10s (26.24Mb)
```

This is my terminal log
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace:

```
$this->pressButton('register');
```

With something like:

```
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
$buttonElement = $page->find('css',".//button[@name='register']");
$buttonElement->click();
```

When you use Selenium Driver, sometimes you can find clue in Selenium Server logs or at least see an exception when something goes wrong.

Also this would be better ;-)

```
PHPUnit::assertNotEmpty($school->isEmpty());
```

Comment: Tried it but it is not helping, I am starting to think this may be the issue with one of the laravel module that I am working with because I tried fresh installation of laravel and it worked like a charm, there are a lot of components like repository patterns, HMVC that i have in my project. I am starting to think this might be the issue.

Comment: I have narrowed the issue down to being that I am submitting the form to the same url and checking if the method is post and it it is a post method, I save the data, this does not work.when I used a different url to store data it is working.

Comment: I am not sure if it helps, but I did notice when I submit form, follow the link, it helps to check something on the page (text, element). If there is no check sometimes tests are randomly failing because Behat was performing step and page wasn't fully loaded yet.